# Node.JS How can different asynchronous chains mutate shared variable without problems?

Tags: javascript, multithreading, node.js, concurrency

I'm fascinated by Node JS and have begun diving in, however, coming from a Java background, I am confused by examples like below where a chain of asynchronous calls are made that rely on a shared variable to keep track (so to determine when they have all completed to perform another action). I apologize if this question is overly basic, however I have been searching on this and haven't found an explanation, I am probably not using the right terms.

If you did something like this in Java, you would need to make the variable n synchronized to avoid collissions, otherwise its integrity could be compromised (this is just pseduo-code based off some more complex examples I read, sorry if its not perfect)

```
    var n = 100

var funct_a = function(callback) {
   return function() {
       if (n == 0)
         callback()
       else
         n--
    }
}

for ( a in someArray) {

  funct_a (function() {
     //do something with variable a...
 })
}
```

Is it that these are only running in one "thread", therefore they are not actually running on different CPU cores and cannot actually write to the variable at the same time? This seems the only logical explanation to me short of some core node server logic that resolves these types of conflicts. Any info to shed some light on this is appreciated.

Comment: I thought NodeJS was single threaded.

Comment: I think it is, but then I see some posts, etc saying it is single-threaded, BUT.... (such as this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7018093/nodejs-really-single-threaded ), basically I think I'm looking for someone who knows more about this than me to confirm that is is at least single threaded always in the context of the example above to ease my mind in writing code like this

Comment: Node.js uses threads internally to handle I/O and computationally expensive operations, but any _JavaScript_ that _you write_ is always executed in a single-threaded environment (this includes callbacks to async IO performed in a thread).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

node.js *is* single-threaded but it sounds like you are more concerned about JavaScript's `closures` and how function scope works in JavaScript. If you had some other code which had access to `n` then in fact, yes, your `callback()` invocation would not behave as you perhaps expected. 
From a higher level perspective though, you should know that the CommonJS module will prevent your `n` variable from being a `global`, so unless you expose it or mess with it inside the module, `n` will not be tampered with. 
You probably already know about this, but I'd recommend touching up on the following:

- JavaScript modular patterns; especially CommonJS for node.js, but also learn AMD
- JavaScript function scope
- JavaScript closures

HTH
Mike

Comment: Thanks for the insightful answer, this clears it up for me, so it seems as long as n is not used by any other code this example would work as expected.

Comment: Glad it helped. One thing you should understand in node.js is the event loop and understand how your code might affect it. A decent article was written on `process.nextTick()` [here](http://howtonode.org/understanding-process-next-tick) that might help out.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the link, I'm loving reading these articles about how Node works, something I didn't realize until now

Answer (score 1):

In node.js all code works synchronously except I/O operations. It is totally different from Java. Try read [this article](http://blog.mixu.net/2011/02/01/understanding-the-node-js-event-loop/) it may help you to undersand.