# Which threading model is used by node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, multithreading

When a new client connects to a server running node.js, does it use

- connection per process
- connection per thread
- request per thread

or something else?

Comment: Do you have a coherent question?

Comment: sorry.. my english is bad.. but my question is: in php for example.. each new connection on the server.. create a new thread in server. My question is.. in node.js?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Node.js is a single-threaded server application.

Comment: I know, I deserve downvotes. :P

Comment: No. It's correct, in part; just also overly-simplified: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7018192. Node.js only offers a single thread for JavaScript execution, but it does use other threads for other tasks.

Comment: I know, I just meant that I deserve downvotes for posting a one-liner answer to a question that would probably be downvoted. :)