# Are nodejs data-structures thread-safe by design?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

Read in a node.js related web document that it is a single threaded server. So it confuses me whether all data structures by default be thread-safe in a node server!

I have multiple call-backs accessing a global object like this :

```
callback1{
global_var['key'] = val;
}

callback2{
globalv_var['key'] = val;
}
```

'key' may be same at times and may be different as well. Will the global_var be thread-safe ?
callbacks, as intended gets called back as and when something is done, in no particular order.

Comment: The callbacks are still executed one after the other. There are no two callbacks operating on the global object at the same time.

Comment: possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7018093/is-nodejs-really-single-threaded

Answer (score 4):

Node.JS contains a "dispatcher."  It accepts web requests and hands them off for asynchronous processing.  That dispatcher is single threaded.  But the dispatcher *spins up a new thread for each task,* and quickly hands off the task to the new thread, freeing the dispatcher's thread for servicing a new request.

To the extent that those task threads are kept separate (i.e. they don't modify each other's state), yes, they are threadsafe.

Answer (score 3):

All of the javascript you write for your node.js applocation executes as if it were running in a single thread.

Any multithreading occurs behind the scenes, in the I/O code and in other native modules. So there's no need to worry about the thread safety of any application code, regardless.

Comment: So background threads invoke on the main thread before doing actual work. And two blocks of work can't run at the same time. Interesting. Similar to a desktop application waiting for user input. And that input kicking off actions in the UI thread.