# Array.forEach thread safety

Tags: javascript, node.js, thread-safety

I am using an array to store a list of connected clients.

Whenever I wish to iterate through the client list I do: `clients.forEach(...)`.

My question is, is this thread safe, as what if a client disconnects (and is therefore removed from `clients`) during the a `clients.forEach(...)` statement?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is yes.

forEach is a synchronous process, meaning that the array would not be modified until the process has finished executing the forEach loop on the array.

This is my understanding from reading:
[Are nodejs data-structures thread-safe by design?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17938768/are-nodejs-data-structures-thread-safe-by-design)

Comment: While the short answer is true, the reasoning is wrong. .forEach is synchronous and thus no other code is running at the same time.

Comment: You should also mention that Node.js is single threaded and therefore threading issues can usually be ignored.

Comment: what if you change the array as part of the fn you are passing to forEach ?x.forEach(function(a){console.log(a);x.push(a)}); Where x is the initial array in the scope.

Comment: the statement "the array would not be modified" is not entirely true. Array can still be modified as part of the fn passed to forEach.

Comment: You are correct that an array can be modified as part of the function passed to forEach, but in this specific case, the array would not be modified.