# Disadvantages of using NodeJS instead of PHP

Tags: php, javascript, node.js

I am thinking of using NodeJS for my website instead of my current PHP + Apache setup. Are there any major disadvatanges/advantages to making this switch?

My site will get lots of small requests and occasional requests that require lots of calculations on the server side.

I have a server that I can install anything I want on, so hosting is not a factor in this decision. Although I would like to maximize performance while minimizing memory and processing requirements.

I guess my main question is, when is NodeJS an appropriate solution for a website?

Answer (score 7):

- You can't use any of the pre-existing PHP applications and libraries.
- You'll need to learn about event-driven programming.

Although those may not always be considered disadvantages *per se*.

Comment: I meant more so in terms of performance, security or functionality.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is not going to disappear immediately, but its positions are undermined even further by the nascent Node.js.
*Node.js is functionally similar to the PHP + Apache or ASP + IIS stacks.*

And there are 2 main advantages:

Speed! (Performance)
Node.js is event-driven and non-blocking and very good at handling [concurrent requests.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200821/grasping-the-node-js-alternative-to-multithreading)
Here is a [link](http://zgadzaj.com/benchmarking-nodejs-basic-performance-tests-against-apache-php) to a benchmarking test for node.js against PHP on Apache.