# How to control concurrency access on a variable in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, concurrency, thread-safety

For example:

```
var i = 0;
while(true)
  http.request('a url', callback_f);

function **callback_f**(){
  **i++**;
}
```

In my simple imaginary example, some request might try to increase i's value in the same time,
How can I write a code which is thread safe in NodeJS?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200821/grasping-the-node-js-alternative-to-multithreading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to worry about threads in Node.js. Node.js handles all calls within a single threaded environment.

Comment: Sounds awesome!
Then I don't need to write something like delegation(in .netframeowrk) in NodeJS?

Comment: I do not know .NET delegation, but in Node.js almost all IO functions are implemented asynchronously which allows the system to call the callbacks in a single threaded manner. This is one of the most powerful properties of Node.js actually.

Comment: @HakanSerce Not *almost all*, all

Comment: @thefortheye There are actually several synchronous APIs in Node.js. Check this for instance, http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.3.1/api/fs.html#fs.readSync

Comment: @HakanSerce What I meant is, there is *no* Node.js function which does only synchronous IO (it may have Sync counterparts)